# How do I say "this is mine"?

Tags: grammar-choice, possessive-pronouns

Suppose I want to say "this house is mine" in Latin. The straightforward translation, *dōmus haec est mea*, sounds odd to me—perhaps just because English changes its possessive pronouns in predicate position. *Dōmus haec est mihi* also sounds odd.

Which of these constructions—or which other construction—is favored in Classical Latin?

Answer (score 3):

It usually depends on where you want the emphasis to lie.

If you simply need to make a general assertion that you are the owner of the house, then you might say *haec est domus mea* — 'this is my house', or 'this house belongs to me'.

If you intend to emphasise that '**this** house [*viz*. not any other] is mine', or '**this** house is the one that is mine', and so on, then you should use the dative of possession — *haec domus est mihi*.

Comment: What if I want to emphasize that this house is **mine**—i.e. have the emphasis on the possessor?

Comment: @Draconis If you don't use the dative, but write as you did _haec est domus mea_, you are saying simply that the house belongs to you, or that the house is in your ownership as opposed to that of anyone else. To reverse the order (i.e. _mea domus_)  is perhaps a little more emphatic.

Answer (score 1):

> Parva mihi domus est sed ianua aperta;

'My house is small but the door is open.' (lit. doors)

This is the first line of ***Mus*** ariddle found in Symphosii Scholastici Ænigmata given in full on [Gianni A. Sarcone's site](http://www.archimedes-lab.org/latin_aenigmata.html)

For 1st person, *mihi est,* and 2nd person, *tibi est,* this is by far the commonest way to say "my" "your," for possession (but not invariably ownership).

In Philip Baldi & Andrea Nuti p314 (Constituent Syntax: Quantification, Numerals, Possession, Anaphora (sadly, £90; but tasteable)) four forms are discussed, which I have oversimplified here:

**Genitive**  Marci est domus (limited to 3rd person)
**Adjective** meus (tuus/ eius) implies possession and ownership and physical presence.
**Dative** mihi est, tibi est (but not 3rd person) more widely used than meus,
**Habeo** habeo is most widely used of all because it includes *non-possessive* (Ihave a cold); *immaterial* (I have a bad feeling about this); *momentary* ( Let us have lunch).

Comment: Not too sure about those four forms. The first is usually construed as dative, and thus no different from the third. The fourth, using _habere_, doesn't strike me as always appropriate to strict classical form : I believe that 'let us have lunch', for instance, is better rendered as _prandeamus_.